# MeteorJS: Import data to MongoDb from an json file selected by the user

Tags: javascript, meteor, upload

I have a meteorjs app and created for the user the functionality to export all his data he created in this app to a json file which he downloads.

Now I wan't to implement the functionality so that he can import this data (e.g. on a different account). I can't find any usable sources for the following:

- General approach in MeteorJS for selecting a file and processing it. Can it be done on the client side? Or rather send the file contents to the server and process it there? Or maybe upload the file to the server and let the server take it and process it?
- How give the user a possibility to select a local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload the file to the server and let the server take it and process it is the most relevant.

To let an user upload a file, you just have to put an input in your html:

```
 <input type="file"/>
```

There are a lot of ideas on Google, I let you search the most relevant for your case (with or without package... ?).
Without any package :

```
Template.myForm.events({
  'submit form': function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var file = template.find('input type=["file"]').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader(); // HTML5
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        Meteor.call("serverSideProcessing", e.target.result, callback);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

Another example : https://doctorllama.wordpress.com/2014/11/06/meteor-upload-package-with-jquery-file-upload/